# Как сделать фиксированный размер ячейки QGridLayout?

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Как сделать фиксированный размер ячейки QGridLayout?

Answer (score 1):

```
QGridLayout::setColumnMinimumWidth(int, int);

QGridLayout::setRowMinimumHeight(int, int)
```

**Дополнение**

У виджета, который ты хочешь разместить в эту ячейку, вызови

```
QWidget::setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed));
```

или можно указать размер виджета вручную:

```
QWidget::setFixedSize(const QSize &);
```

или отдельно высоту или ширину:

```
QWidget::setFixedWidth(int); 
QWidget::setFixedHeight(int);
```

Comment: не минимальный, а фиксированный

Comment: У виджета, который ты хочешь разместить в эту ячейку, вызови `QWidget::setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed));`

или можно указать размер виджета вручную:

`QWidget::setFixedSize(const QSize &);`

или отдельно высоту или ширину:

`QWidget::setFixedWidth(int);`
`QWidget::setFixedHeight(int)`